# Your submission was not accepted.Here is an explanation:The call capital_indexes('HI') should return'[0, 1]',but it returned '[0, 1, 0, 1]'

Tags: python

```
    lst = []  
    def capital_indexes(s):  
        for i in s:  
            if i.isupper():  
                lst.append(s.index(i))  
            else:  
                pass  
        print(lst)  
        return lst  

capital_indexes("HI")
```

I don't understand :(
I use a website called https://pythonprinciples.com/challenges/Capital-indexes/

Comment: When I run this code in the site you mention it returns [0,1]

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that your `lst=[]` is only run once, but the website will call your function multiple times. You never clear the list, so it will always be appended to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst` is a global list. Hence it will aggregate the outputs of all the calls to `capital_indexes`.

The output list should be local:

```
def capital_indexes(s):  
    lst = []
    for i in s:  
        if i.isupper():  
            lst.append(s.index(i))  
        else:  
            pass  
    print(lst)  
    return lst
```

BTW, `lst.append(s.index(i))` will return the wrong output anyway if the string has duplicated uppercase letters since `list.index` returns the first index of the element.

It's easier to use a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    return [index for index, ch in enumerate(s) if ch.isupper()]
```

or without comprehension:

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    lst = []
    for index, ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch.isupper():
            lst.append(index)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the erroneous output is because list `lst` is a global list. Online judges run multiple test cases on the code submitted my user to check for it's correctness. Because,list `lst` is declared globally it will cause the list to accumulate answers of previous test cases executed by online judge.

You can solve this error by declaring list `lst` inside of the scope of function `capital_indexes()`. If you wish to keep `lst` as a global list, you can clear your list at start of function by calling `lst.clear()` .

Your code logic is flawed too. `s.index(i)` will return the index of first occurance of the character `i` in the string. In case the input string contains multiple occurances of same character, this code logic will be incorrect.

Here, are 2 implementation of the function `capital_indexes()`.

- Implementation with a local list

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    lst = []
    for idx,element in enumerate(s):
        if element.isupper():
            lst.append(idx)
    return lst
```

- Implementation with a global list

```
lst = []
def capital_indexes(s):
    lst.clear()
    for idx,element in enumerate(s):
        if element.isupper():
            lst.append(idx)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not result in the correct answer when there would be 2 of the same capitals in the input string.
`string.index(sub_string)` returns the first occurrence of the sub_string in the string.

Try:

```py
def capital_indexes(s):  
    lst = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isupper():  
            lst.append(i)
    return lst  

capital_indexes("HeLlI")  #[0,2,4]
capital_indexes("HeLLo")  #[0,2,3] your code would give [0,2,2]
```

Here I use enumerate to get the index (`i`) of the character (`c`). Because you now know on which index the uppercase letters are, you can simply append this to the list.

Comment: Right, but the erroneous output in OP's example is because they are using a global list.